# Как использовать environment value?

Tags: xcode, ios

Всем привет!

Сделал scheme,в нем environment value (например, TEST)

В коде, в AppDelegate пишу:

```
#if TEST
//do some actions
#endif
```

Но это не работает. Как правильно использовать environment value?

Comment: @Troir, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Вы путаете два понятия - переменные среды и директивы препроцессора. Переменные среды определяются на каждом компе индивидуально и служат чем-то типа настроек для кучи программ сразу, например, $HOME всегда дает ссылку на директорию пользователя где бы та не находилась внутри файловой системы, до них вполне можно достучаться в момент исполнения программы. Директивы препроцессора же служат для того чтобы из одних и тех же сырцов можно было на выходе получать программы с несколько разным функционалом или данными, они существуют только до момента сборки программы, а после сборки в рантайме такого понятия уже нет - в зависимости от того что это была за директива она либо подменяется на какой-то другой набор символов(макросы), либо выкидывается вообще (`#pragma mark`), либо еще что-то делает (скажем, `#warning` генерит собственно warning).

Конкретно в вашем случае вы, по видимому, задали в схеме именно что переменную среды TEST, а в коде пытаетесь работать с директивой препроцессора TEST у которых общего только имя. Чтобы код внутри `#if TEST` попал в компилятор вообще нужно чтобы где-то была определена директива TEST, сделать это можно либо в коде с помощью `#define TEST`, либо в схеме в каком-то из свойств наподобие `PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITION` или `PREPROCESSOR_MACROS`  -  не помню как оно сейчас называется (название несколько раз меняли), но насколько помню там же в схемах Release и Debug болтаются одноименные директивы - ориентируйтесь на них. А в принципе можно даже добавить флаг непосредственно компилятору `-D TEST`

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!

Я только не совсем понял, как решить вопрос. Мне надо, чтобы при запуске разных scheme приложение запускалось с разными параметрами. Например, если запущена схема 1, то выводится в лог сообщение "Привет, мир!", а если запущена схема 2, то в лог выводится "Пока, мир!". Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Я же написал - надо директиву указать где-то в свойствах схемы, свойство будет называться preprocessor - что-то там, AlexThumb привел ссылку где есть скриншот. Точнее без проверки в xcode именно той же версии что у вас сказать не получится - названии и местоположение могут отличаться. Когда будете искать не забудьте включить показ всех свойств - таб в верхнем левом углу

Answer (score 1):

Принятый ответ в [данном](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063100/xcode-ios-how-to-determine-whether-code-is-running-in-debug-release-build) вопросе показывает на скриншоте, где именно необходимо указать значение, которое Вы хотите использовать. Конкретно - это раздел Preprocessor Macros, можете найти его через поиск в правом верхнем углу окошка.